# Is there a way for me to make an <input> field non-editable

Tags: html, css

I have some fields that are currently input fields. Some should allow edits and others not. Without changing them from input fields, is there a simple way to make it so I cannot edit these? I'm looking for just one CSS or other kind of property if that exists.

thanks

Mariko

Answer (score 9):

You can add the [readonly="readonly"](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp) attribute to the input elements.

Comment: +1. `readonly` will prevent the user from editing the input, but any value contained in it will still be submitted. To completely disable an input field so no value gets submitted, use `disabled="disabled"`

Answer (score 4):

Or `disabled`: `<input disabled>`

You can style both with CSS:

`input:disabled` or `input[disabled]` for disabled

`input[readonly]` for readonly

Comment: how would be an style defined using input[readonly] ? I can't manage to get it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" id="id" name="id" value="" readonly="readonly" />
```

Answer (score 1):

either

```
<textarea ... readonly="readonly"></textarea>
```

and/or :

```
<textarea ... disabled="true"></textarea>
```

I prefer readonly -attribute, which just prevents modifying. Disabled attribute makes the whole area look disabled (grey) and disabled textarea's data isn't submitted, when a form is posted.